# Rails 2 plain text mail showing wrong indentation/format in Thunderbird

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-2, thunderbird

I am using rails 2.3 and want to send multipart plain/html emails. The html emails gets delivered in proper format, but the text emails shows wrong format sometimes.
This is my notifier method:

```
part :content_type => 'multipart/alternative' do |copy|
      copy.part :content_type => 'text/plain' do |plain|
        plain.body = render( :file => "file.text.plain.erb",  :body => @body )
        plain.transfer_encoding = "base64"
```

Expected Output:-

> Hi user,
>
> Welcome to your shop.
>
> ---
>
> Our customer service team will be at your service right after a moment.
>
> Your plan activated is Demo.
>
> ---
>
> In case of any difficulty, feel free to contact us.
>
> ---
>
> www.exampleshop.com

This output comes fine in gmail, yahoomail and other web mail services.

But sometimes it comes garbled in mail clients such as Thunderbird , Outlook and Evolution in this way:-

> Hi user,
>
> Welcome to your shop. 
>    ------------------------ Our customer service team will be at your service right after a moment.
>
> Your plan activated is Demo. ---------------------------
>
> In case of any difficulty, feel free to contact us. ----------------------------------------------------- www.exampleshop.com

I have `ActionMailer::Base.default_charset = "utf-8"`

Also could this be an encoding issue?

Kindly suggest.